# Evaluate the integral: integral of $\int 6^{-2x} dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\displaystyle \int6^{-2x}dx$$

I got $-\dfrac{6^{-2x}}{2\ln6}$  but I'm not confident that its correct.

Comment: Our function is $e^{-x(2\ln 6)}$. So you are right, apart from the missing $+C$.

Comment: differentiate your result, if you get the same function you are integrating, then your result is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=6^{-2x}$, then
\begin{align}
\ln y=\ln\left(6^{-2x}\right)=-2x\ln6\qquad\rightarrow\qquad y=e^{-(2\ln6)x}
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\int6^{-2x}\,dx&=\int e^{-(2\ln6)x}\,dx
\end{align}
Remember
\begin{align}
\int e^{ax}\,dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a}+C
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\int6^{-2x}\,dx&=\int e^{-(2\ln6)x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{e^{-(2\ln6)x}}{-(2\ln6)}+C\\
&=-\frac{e^{-(2\ln6)x}}{2\ln6}+C\\
&=-\frac{6^{-2x}}{2\ln6}+C\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Our integral is:
$$\int 6^{-2x} \ dx$$
Rewrite the integral:
$$\int \left(6^{-2}\right)^x \ dx$$
$$=\int \left(\frac{1}{36}\right)^x \ dx$$
Remember that:
$$\int a^x \ dx=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}+C$$
In this case our $a$ is $\frac{1}{36}$
$$\int \left(\frac 1{36}\right)^x \ dx=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{36}\right)^x}{\ln \left(\frac{1}{36}\right)}+C$$
$$=\frac{6^{-2x}}{\ln\left(6^{-2}\right)}+C$$
$$=-\frac{6^{-2x}}{2 \ln 6}+C$$
Hope I helped!

Comment: what was the purpose of rewriting $6^{-2}$ as $\frac{1}{36}$  if you just substituted back in as soon as you integrated? looks nicer i guess

Comment: @MichaelT I don't have the ability to look ahead and see how my answer would turn out (note: not sarcasm). Both ways are fine I think